# why dont work utf8 methode post in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

why dont work utf8 at methode post for show data in Screen

[image]

Comment: please don't share photo or screen instead post entire code.visit [why-not-upload-images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: What do you mean by "don't work"? do you get any errors?